# Simple questions regarding table that spans into multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, xltabular

The following code creates a table that spans into two pages. However, I am running into three issues:

1. The table does not fit into the page properly and is aligned in a strange way. I earlier used `tabularx` and that table was fitting well (on a given page, but was not spanning to the next page_. Although the post that @Werner re-directed me earlier provides some useful tips, I am running into these issues. Is there an easy way to solve this issue? To show that I want to achieve, please see the picture, Example 1, below (which was constructed using `tabularx`) that has the table properly centred.
2. Similarly, the rows are also now not aligned and there are uneven gaps in between rows. Again, Example 1 does not run into such an issue.
3. This is a minor question, but as in Example 1, the very first line is thicker than the below lines. Is there any way to do this with longtable (i.e., the code below)?

That said, I need to thank @leandriis for trying to help out earlier with a similar question. Although @leandriis kindly suggested that I should use `xltabular`, I was not able to find many useful examples that allows me to construct the table using this package.  @leandriis, do you think the three above points can be solved with `xltabular`?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**Here is the code:**

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}M{8em}ccccccc@{}}
  \caption{Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing}\\[-1.5ex]
  \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize  Something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something. }  
  \\ [8ex]
\toprule
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\ 

 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)& (7) \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{continues from the previous page}\\
\midrule
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\

\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}r@{}}{continues on the next page}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

$\mathbbm{1}${(Not Social Distancing$_{j,t}$)}
 & 0.322& 0.278& 0.276 & 0.387*** & 0.304*** & 0.305*** & 0.381*** \\
 & (0.3333) & (0.2232) & (0.2323) & (0.333) & (0.334) & (0.334) & (0.333) \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Pnst  Type$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.331*** & 0.331*** &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.3359) & (0.3359) &  \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Long variable name$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & -0.3315 & -0.3313 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.3313) & (0.3313) &  \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Intense 3$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.07** & 0.08** & 0.06* \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\  
 $\mathbbm{1}${(Insurance$_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 0.133 & 0.149 & 0.114 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.090) & (0.090) & (0.091) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Gender$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3*** & 0.3*** & 0.07** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.021) & (0.021) & (0.067) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Facility P$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.006 & 0.005 & 0.025** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.033) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Att$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3345 & 0.0234 & 0.0215 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.038) & (0.042) & (0.333) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Ptt$_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 0.0988 & 0.0849 & 0.0873 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.153) & (0.151) & (0.203) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{[1,5],}$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.315 & 0.327 & 0.229 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.206) & (0.202) & (0.200) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(5,11],}$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & -0.336 & 0.025 & 0.007 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.043) & (0.042) & (0.023) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(11,20],}$ $_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & -0.43** & -0.33** & -0.40** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.178) & (0.175) & (0.185) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(20,35],}$ $_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 1.203** & 1.116** & 1.066* \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.534) & (0.538) & (0.565) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{>35},$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.020 & 0.030 & 0.003 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.0420) & (0.0433) & (0.0219) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 1$_{j,t}$)}  &  &  &  &  & 0.291*** & 0.218** & 0.213** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.119) & (0.116) & (0.0846) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 2$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3392 & 0.0823 & 0.0702 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.337) & (0.337) & (0.117) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 3$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.0250 & 0.0207 & 0.3379 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.021) & (0.021) & (0.023) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 4$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.0621 & -0.334 & -0.3355 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.120) & (0.339) & (0.121) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 5$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.137 & 0.355** & 0.123 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.160) & (0.157) & (0.166) \\  

 \hline 

\midrule
\textbf{Fixed Effects} \\     
Time &X&X&X&X&X&X&X \\    
Country &&X&X&&X&X & \\    
Time$\times$Country &&&X&&&X & \\    
Location &&&&X&&&X \\    
\midrule
Observations & 16,175 & 16,175 & 16,158 & 16,059 & 15,041 & 15,041 & 14,941 \\  
 R-squared & 0.095 & 0.144 & 0.193 & 0.353 & 0.171 & 0.205 & 0.357 \\ \hline


\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Modification:** 
Following the suggestion made by @Bernard, I have modified the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\vspace*{-3cm}
\begin{xltabular}[l]{0.55\linewidth}{@{}X*8{c}@{}}
  \caption{Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing}\\[-1.5ex]
  \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize  Something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something. }  \\ [8ex]
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\ 

 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)& (7) \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l@{}}{continues from the previous page}\\
\midrule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\

\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{@{}r@{}}{continues on the next page}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

$\mathbbm{1}${(Not Social Distancing$_{j,t}$)}
 & 0.322& 0.278& 0.276 & 0.387*** & 0.304*** & 0.305*** & 0.381*** \\ 
 & (0.3333) & (0.2232) & (0.2323) & (0.333) & (0.334) & (0.334) & (0.333) \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Pnst  Type$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.331*** & 0.331*** &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.3359) & (0.3359) &  \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Long variable name$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & -0.3315 & -0.3313 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.3313) & (0.3313) &  \\   
$\mathbbm{1}${(Intense 3$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.07** & 0.08** & 0.06* \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\  
 $\mathbbm{1}${(Insurance$_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 0.133 & 0.149 & 0.114 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.090) & (0.090) & (0.091) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Gender$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3*** & 0.3*** & 0.07** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.021) & (0.021) & (0.067) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Facility P$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.006 & 0.005 & 0.025** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.008) & (0.008) & (0.033) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Att$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3345 & 0.0234 & 0.0215 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.038) & (0.042) & (0.333) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Ptt$_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 0.0988 & 0.0849 & 0.0873 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.153) & (0.151) & (0.203) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{[1,5],}$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.315 & 0.327 & 0.229 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.206) & (0.202) & (0.200) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(5,11],}$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & -0.336 & 0.025 & 0.007 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.043) & (0.042) & (0.023) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(11,20],}$ $_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & -0.43** & -0.33** & -0.40** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.178) & (0.175) & (0.185) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{(20,35],}$ $_{j,t}$)}&  &  &  &  & 1.203** & 1.116** & 1.066* \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.534) & (0.538) & (0.565) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Variable 3$_{>35},$ $_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.020 & 0.030 & 0.003 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.0420) & (0.0433) & (0.0219) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 1$_{j,t}$)}  &  &  &  &  & 0.291*** & 0.218** & 0.213** \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.119) & (0.116) & (0.0846) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 2$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.3392 & 0.0823 & 0.0702 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.337) & (0.337) & (0.117) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 3$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.0250 & 0.0207 & 0.3379 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.021) & (0.021) & (0.023) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 4$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.0621 & -0.334 & -0.3355 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.120) & (0.339) & (0.121) \\  
$\mathbbm{1}${(Age Group 5$_{j,t}$)} &  &  &  &  & 0.137 & 0.355** & 0.123 \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.160) & (0.157) & (0.166) \\  

 \hline 

\midrule
\textbf{Fixed Effects} \\     
Time &X&X&X&X&X&X&X \\    
Country &&X&X&&X&X & \\    
Time$\times$Country &&&X&&&X & \\    
Location &&&&X&&&X \\    
\midrule
Observations & 16,175 & 16,175 & 16,158 & 16,059 & 15,041 & 15,041 & 14,941 \\  
 R-squared & 0.095 & 0.144 & 0.193 & 0.353 & 0.171 & 0.205 & 0.357 \\ \hline


\end{xltabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

This code works well except of that the column lengths are not the same for each column (i.e., columns 5, 6, 7 have much larger gaps in between).

Comment: For the first point, you can use the `xltabular` environment, from the homonymous package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx` (same syntax as longtable). For the second point, it's not very bclear to me. Could you explain more?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. So, changing the `\begin{longtable}` to `\begin{xltabular}` would solve the issue? Regarding the second point, in between the first row (coefficient of Not Social Distancing) and the second row, there is a larger gap than, for example, the gap that comes right after the standard error (i.e., rows 2 and 3).

Comment: @Bernard, I just tried changing the package to `\begin{xltabular}`, but the table still does not look correct.

Comment: Yes, it would be enough to fit the page. However, remember a tabularx environment requires at least one `X` column.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. I just change the function to `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X}`, but the table does not look correct. I am not sure what exactly you mean by columns. Would you be kind to make the change and post the example? Thanks in advance..

Comment: The table preamble should be, for instance `{@{}X*7{c}@{}}`, but it seems to resist (elsarticle class?). I'll look at it tomorrow (it's getting late here) if no one has solved your problem.

Comment: @Bernard, I believe I figured out something that I will post right below my question above. There is, however, still a small issue. I will post my question there.

Comment: I just posted the modified version, @Bernard. When I change the page to landscape, things look much better with your suggestion. However, another issue arises. Namely, the gaps between each column are uneven. In other words, there are larger gap between columns 6 and 7 compare to the gap between columns 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- very. very actual table ...
- I would use `S` columns for columns 2 -- 8
- calculation of `\tabcolsep` left to LaTeX
- for table use `longtable` with settings `\setlength\LTleft{0pt}\setlength\LTright{0pt}`
- reduce table's font size to `\small`:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\sisetup{table-format=1.4,
         table-space-text-pre=(,
         table-space-text-post=***,
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-symbols=()
         }
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}    M{8em}
                                           *{7}{S}}
\caption[Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing]
        {Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing\\[1ex]
        \footnotesize  
        Something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something. }
\label{tab:čongtable-covit-19}  \\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing (cont.)} \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}r@{}}{\footnotesize\textit{continues on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot

$\mathbbm{1}$ (Not Social Distancing$_{j,t}$)
    & 0.322     & 0.278     & 0.276     & 0.387***  & 0.304***  & 0.305***  & 0.381***  \\
    & (0.3333)  & (0.2232)  & (0.2323)  & (0.333)   & (0.334)   & (0.334)   & (0.333)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Pnst  Type$_{j,t}$)    
    &           &           &           &           & 0.331***  & 0.331***  &           \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.3359)  & (0.3359)  &           \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Long variable name$_{j,t}$)    
    &           &           &           &           & -0.3315   & -0.3313   &           \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.3313)  & (0.3313)  &           \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Intense 3$_{j,t}$)     
    &           &           &           &           & 0.07**    & 0.08**    & 0.06*     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Insurance$_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.133     & 0.149     & 0.114     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.090)   & (0.090)   & (0.091)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Gender$_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3***    & 0.3***    & 0.07**    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.021)   & (0.021)   & (0.067)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Facility P$_{j,t}$)  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.006     & 0.005     & 0.025**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.008)   & (0.008)   & (0.033)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Att$_{j,t}$)  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3345    & 0.0234    & 0.0215    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.042)   & (0.333)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Ptt$_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0988    & 0.0849    & 0.0873    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.153)   & (0.151)   & (0.203)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Variable 3$_{[1,5],}$ $_{j,t}$)  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.315     & 0.327     & 0.229     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.206)   & (0.202)   & (0.200)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Variable 3$_{(5,11],}$ $_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & -0.336    & 0.025     & 0.007     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.042)   & (0.023)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Variable 3$_{(11,20],}$ $_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & -0.43**   & -0.33**   & -0.40**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.178)   & (0.175)   & (0.185)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Variable 3$_{(20,35],}$ $_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 1.203**   & 1.116**   & 1.066*    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.534)   & (0.538)   & (0.565)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Variable 3$_{>35},$ $_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.020     & 0.030     & 0.003     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.0420)  & (0.0433)  & (0.0219)  \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Age Group 1$_{j,t}$)   
    &           &           &           &           & 0.291***  & 0.218**   & 0.213**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.116)   & (0.0846)  \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Age Group 2$_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3392    & 0.0823    & 0.0702    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.337)   & (0.337)   & (0.117)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Age Group 3$_{j,t}$) 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0250    & 0.0207    & 0.3379    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.021)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Age Group 4$_{j,t}$)  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0621    & -0.334    & -0.3355   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.120)   & (0.339)   & (0.121)   \\
$\mathbbm{1}$ (Age Group 5$_{j,t}$)  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.137     & 0.355**   & 0.123     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.160)   & (0.157)   & (0.166)   \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Fixed Effects} \\
Time    
    & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       \\
Country 
    &           & {X}       & {X}       &           & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       \\
Time$\times$Country 
    &           &           & {X}       &           &           & {X}       &           \\
Location
    &           &           &           & {X}       &           &           & {X}       \\
\midrule
Observations    
    & {16,175}  & {16,175}  & {16,158}  & {16,059}  & {15,041}  & {15,041}  & {14,941}  \\
R-squared       
    & 0.095     & 0.144     & 0.193     & 0.353     & 0.171     & 0.205     & 0.357     \\
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**
It is not clear the meaning of `$\mathbbm{1}$` before cells in the in the first column contents. I would remove them together parenthesis around cell contents. With this is obtained a bit more space for table. Also I would introduce small vertical space between each second row in the first part of table. IN the seccond part of table is consider your ask in comments below:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-format=1.4,
         table-space-text-pre=(,
         table-space-text-post=***,
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-symbols=(),
         table-alignment=right
         }
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l
                                           *{7}{S}}
\caption[Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing]
        {Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing\\[1ex]
        \footnotesize  
        Something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something. }
\label{tab:čongtable-covit-19}  \\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \mcc{(1)} & \mcc{(2)} & \mcc{(3)} & \mcc{(4)} & \mcc{(5)} & \mcc{(6)} & \mcc{(7)} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Coronavirus rates as a logarithmic function of social distancing (cont.)} \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Dependent Variable: $\mathbbm{1}${(Death$_{j,t}$)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \mcc{(1)} & \mcc{(2)} & \mcc{(3)} & \mcc{(4)} & \mcc{(5)} & \mcc{(6)} & \mcc{(7)} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{@{}r@{}}{\footnotesize\textit{continues on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Not Social Distancing$_{j,t}$
    & 0.322     & 0.278     & 0.276     & 0.387***  & 0.304***  & 0.305***  & 0.381***  \\
    & (0.3333)  & (0.2232)  & (0.2323)  & (0.333)   & (0.334)   & (0.334)   & (0.333)   \\
    \addlinespace
Pnst  Type$_{j,t}$    
    &           &           &           &           & 0.331***  & 0.331***  &           \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.3359)  & (0.3359)  &           \\
    \addlinespace
Long variable name$_{j,t}$    
    &           &           &           &           & -0.3315   & -0.3313   &           \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.3313)  & (0.3313)  &           \\
    \addlinespace
Intense 3$_{j,t}$     
    &           &           &           &           & 0.07**    & 0.08**    & 0.06*     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.000)   & (0.000)   & (0.000)   \\
    \addlinespace
Insurance$_{j,t}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.133     & 0.149     & 0.114     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.090)   & (0.090)   & (0.091)   \\
    \addlinespace
Gender$_{j,t}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3***    & 0.3***    & 0.07**    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.021)   & (0.021)   & (0.067)   \\
    \addlinespace
Facility P$_{j,t}$  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.006     & 0.005     & 0.025**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.008)   & (0.008)   & (0.033)   \\
    \addlinespace
Att$_{j,t}$  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3345    & 0.0234    & 0.0215    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.042)   & (0.333)   \\
    \addlinespace
Ptt$_{j,t}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0988    & 0.0849    & 0.0873    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.153)   & (0.151)   & (0.203)   \\
    \addlinespace
Variable 3$_{[1,5]\;j,t}$  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.315     & 0.327     & 0.229     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.206)   & (0.202)   & (0.200)   \\
    \addlinespace
Variable 3$_{(5,11],\;j,t)}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & -0.336    & 0.025     & 0.007     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.042)   & (0.023)   \\
    \addlinespace
Variable 3$_{(11,20],\;j,t)}$
    &           &           &           &           & -0.43**   & -0.33**   & -0.40**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.178)   & (0.175)   & (0.185)   \\
    \addlinespace
Variable 3$_{(20,35],\;j,t)}$
    &           &           &           &           & 1.203**   & 1.116**   & 1.066*    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.534)   & (0.538)   & (0.565)   \\
    \addlinespace
Variable 3$_{>35,\;j,t}$
    &           &           &           &           & 0.020     & 0.030     & 0.003     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.0420)  & (0.0433)  & (0.0219)  \\
    \addlinespace
Age Group 1$_{j,t}$   
    &           &           &           &           & 0.291***  & 0.218**   & 0.213**   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.116)   & (0.0846)  \\
    \addlinespace
Age Group 2$_{j,t}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.3392    & 0.0823    & 0.0702    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.337)   & (0.337)   & (0.117)   \\
    \addlinespace
Age Group 3$_{j,t}$ 
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0250    & 0.0207    & 0.3379    \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.021)   & (0.021)   & (0.023)   \\
    \addlinespace
Age Group 4$_{j,t}$  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.0621    & -0.334    & -0.3355   \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.120)   & (0.339)   & (0.121)   \\
    \addlinespace
Age Group 5$_{j,t}$  
    &           &           &           &           & 0.137     & 0.355**   & 0.123     \\
    &           &           &           &           & (0.160)   & (0.157)   & (0.166)   \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Fixed Effects} \\
Time    
    & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       \\
Country 
    &           & {X}       & {X}       &           & {X}       & {X}       & {X}       \\
Time$\times$Country 
    &           &           & {X}       &           &           & {X}       &           \\
Location
    &           &           &           & {X}       &           &           & {X}       \\
\midrule
Observations    
    & {16,175}  & {16,175}  & {16,158}  & {16,059}  & {15,041}  & {15,041}  & {14,941}  \\
R-squared       
    & {0.095}     & {0.144} & {0.193}   & {0.353}   & {0.171}   & {0.205}   & {0.357}   \\
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

- `S` columns are defined in`siunitx` package. They are use for align numbers at decimal points.
- In settings are define features of `S` solumns as follows:

  - Size of numbers with `tabular-format=<num. of inteders>.>num of decimal digits`.
  - Additional space before numbers with `table-space-text-pre=(`.
  - Additional space after numbers with `table-space-text-pre=***`.
  - Align back parenthesize and `*` after number with `table-align-text-post=false`.
  - Input symbols, whic are consider with numbers formation (`)`, `)`, which are used in tables) with `input-symbols=()`
  - for right align text in `S` columns serve `table-alignment=right` (according to my test, I would omit this option and use default setting, which is `center`. In this case you ca alo delete definition of `\mcc` command as well its use in table headers, as is done in the first example).
- To have cells' contents in the first column, you just replace `M` column with`l`, but with this you need to reduce column size, that table can be fit in text width.

Comment: That looks awesome. Many thanks, @Zarko. One quick question. Is there any way to align the numbers following R-squared so that they are right below the numbers of the above row?

Comment: @Job. yes, it is  possible. See addendum to answer, where beside this your  wish I also add some more tweaks to table design.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Zarko. One similar issue, the X's right after "Time" are somehow in between "Fixed Effects" and "Time". I added another `\\`, but that comments seems to be ignored.

Comment: Very last question, I assume trying to fit in the variable names into each row would not be possible, right? For example, the first variable, fitting `$\mathbbm{1}$ (Not Social Distancing$_{j,t}$)` into one single row (rather than two rows) wouldn't be possible without sacrificing to expand the table width, right?

Comment: now it looks really nice! Many thanks. One very last point, the column names (1), (2), ..., (7) are now not enlightened with the first row. I think that would be the very last issue. Otherwise, the table would look perfect..

Comment: I assume one would just need to add `{}` outside the numbers?

Comment: @Job, it is already corrected. I forgot on it when writing addendum :-(. No, now is table as should be. cell's content in curly braces is aligned right (as you desired, however, i would rather left them centered in cells, as is usual done in such tables) other numbers ar aligned at decimal points.

Comment: That's perfectly fine @Zarko. Is there any other way to align the column numbers other than than add `{}` outside the numbers?

Comment: I need to construct about 20 tables like this and it would be super painful to add these manually (since my tables are exported automatically to LaTeX).

Comment: I just re-ran your code and it looks now amazing!! I guess you were able to fix it without adding the `{}`. How exactly did you align the columns?

Comment: to show my appreciation, I have been liking a ton of your great answers :-) Cheers, thanks again.

Comment: @Job, thank you very much, see edited answer.

Comment: AMAZING! All is now super clear. Many thanks!!! You're the best and very helpful, to be frank.